# PSQL- Query that can find two different specified limits for two different conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find 5 livestreams that have over 1000 watchers and 5 that are under a 1000 watchers with a WHERE statement searching for one category or another.

Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE current_livestream (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users,
  watching integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  play_url text NOT NULL,
  category text NOT NULL,
  description text NOT NULL,
  stream_start timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
);
```

Here is the current query.

```
`SELECT 
          cl.play_url, 
          cl.category, 
          cl.description, 
          cl.watching
        FROM current_livestream cl
        WHERE cl.category = 'gaming' OR cl.category = 'art'
        LIMIT ${total}`
```

Sample Data

```
 id | user_id | watching | play_url | category | description  |        stream_start        
----+---------+----------+----------+----------+--------------+----------------------------
  1 |       1 |     1232 | http     | gaming   | warzone      | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
  2 |       2 |      456 | http     | gaming   | fornite      | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
  3 |       3 |      121 | http     | gaming   | warzone      | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
  4 |       4 |      347 | http     | gaming   | mario        | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
  5 |       5 |     1232 | http     | gaming   | tony hawk    | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
  6 |       1 |       32 | http     | gaming   | warzone      | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
  7 |       1 |    10232 | http     | gaming   | halo         | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
  8 |       1 |     1232 | http     | art      | painting     | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
  9 |       1 |    12343 | http     | art      | woodshop     | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
 10 |       1 |      232 | http     | art      | singing      | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
 11 |       1 |    11111 | http     | chatting | world events | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
 12 |       1 |     1000 | http     | cooking  | clam chowder | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
 13 |       1 |       55 | http     | cooking  | spaghetti    | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
 14 |       1 |    99999 | http     | art      | bob ross     | 2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636
(14 rows)
```

Desired Results

```
 play_url | category | description | watching 
----------+----------+-------------+----------
http       gaming     warzone        1232
http       gaming     fortnite       456
http       art        painting       1232
http       art        woodshop       12343
http       gaming     warzone        121
http       gaming     mario          347
http       gaming     tony hawk      1232
http       art        singing        232
http       gaming     warzone        32
http       gaming     halo           10232
```

Is there anyway I can do this in one query or do I have to do two?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Added that for you

Comment: . . Your query references two tables.  These are explained nowhere in the question and the sample data doesn't correspond to the query.

Comment: My bad I took out the JOIN. Sorry bout that

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accomplish this with 1 query, it requires 2. However, you can combine the result sets into a single result set using UNION (ALL). Effectively reducing in 1 query but with 2 sub queries. The following produces the same rows as the requested output, but does not produce the same sequence. I can find no commonality in the column to produce the indicated order. Further without a specific  order by the sequence in the final output is arbitrary and may very well not be consistent.

Note the use of a CTE in place of a table.

```
 with current_livestream (id, user_id, watching, play_url, category, description, stream_start) as             
      ( values ( 1,1, 1232, 'http', 'gaming'   , 'warzone'     , '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
             , ( 2,2,  456, 'http', 'gaming'   , 'fornite'     , '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
             , ( 3,3,  121, 'http', 'gaming'   , 'warzone'     , '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
             , ( 4,4,  347, 'http', 'gaming'   , 'mario'       , '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
             , ( 5,5, 1232, 'http', 'gaming'   , 'tony haw'    , '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
             , ( 6,1,   32, 'http', 'gaming'   , 'warzone'     , '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
             , ( 7,1,10232, 'http', 'gaming'   , 'halo'        , '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
             , ( 8,1, 1232, 'http', 'art'      , 'painting'    , '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
             , ( 9,1,12343, 'http', 'art'      , 'woodshop'    , '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
             , (10,1,  232, 'http', 'art'      , 'singing '    , '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
             , (11,1,11111, 'http', 'chatting' , 'world events', '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
             , (12,1, 1000, 'http', 'cooking'  , 'clam chowder', '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
             , (13,1,   55, 'http', 'cooking'  , 'spaghetti'   , '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
             , (14,1,99999, 'http', 'art'      , 'bob ross'    , '2021-04-15 14:30:47.487636'::timestamp)      
      )                                                                                                        
select *                                                                                                       
  from ( select play_url                                                                                       
              , category                                                                                       
              , description                                                                                    
              , watching                                                                                       
           from current_livestream                                                                             
          where watching > 1000                                                                                
            and category in ('gaming', 'art')                                                                  
          order by id                                                                                          
           limit 5                                                                                             
        ) g1000                                                                                                
      union all                                                                                                
       (select play_url                                                                                        
             , category                                                                                        
             , description                                                                                     
             , watching                                                                                        
          from current_livestream                                                                              
         where watching < 1000                                                                               
           and category in ('gaming', 'art')                                                                   
          order by id                                                                                          
         limit 5                                                                                               
       );
```